# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression'

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using [LinqKit.dll](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to do Linq To Entity in my application, as follow :

```
qry = _articleRepo.GetItemsByCulture(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)
                                .AsExpandable().Where(x => x.Approved && isInCategory(x.CategoryID, category.CategoryID));

 Func<string, int, bool> isInCategory = (x, y) =>
            {
                IQueryable<string> list = x.Split(',').AsQueryable();

                //Except 
                //x.Except(_);

                return list.Any(z => z == y.ToString());
            };
```

it gives me error :

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

but removing isInCategory(x.CategoryID, category.CategoryID) causes the application to run without problem.

Would please help me ?

Comment: Short answer: There is no way to make this work. Because your method cannot be translated to SQL. Usual way to do this is using SQL function and map it to application but that is only possible if you are using EDMX for mapping.

Comment: It mas seem weird but buy using Unit of Work pattern, my application works properly now.

Comment: I can't tell for sure if this is the case from your question (which is why this is not an answer), but if `isInCategory` is not a local variable, then you'll get that error. If it's not, then add a line before the `qry` line that says something like `var expression = isInCategory;` and then use `expression` in the `qry` line.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after looking at the code in comments, I can suggest following:
Replace `string CategoryID` on Article to `public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }`, so EF will create a foreign key. Then, in order to get articles, that are in particular category, you can use code similar to the following:

```
var articlesInCategory = context.Articles
            .Where(x => x.Language == Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)
            .Where(x => x.Approved && x.Categories.Any(c => c.CategoryID == c1.CategoryID)).ToList();
```

And when you want to create new articles, you should use something like:

```
var c1 = context.Categories.OrderBy(c => c.Title).First();
var c2 = context.Categories.OrderBy(c => c.Title).Skip(1).First();
context.Articles.Add(new Article { Categories = new Collection<Category> { c1, c2 } });
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: is there any sample for that ?

Comment: As I understand your isInCategory method. You associate categories with items via listing them in item.CategoryID separated by commas. If you don`t want to change architecture, then you can replace isInCategory, by simple x.CategoryID.Contains(category.CategoryID). This should work almost the same way. Personally I would prefer to maintain the association of items with categories by foreign key.

Comment: Like, you have three table: Items{ItemId, ItemData...}, Categories{CategoryID}, ItemsInCategory{ItemId, CetagoryID}. This way ORM will generate list on both entities (item.Categories and categoty.Items). Then in your query you will be able to use something like: context.Items.Where(i => i.Categories.Contains(category));

Comment: By using isInCategory, I check whether an the article is in specified category |(category.CategoryID) or not, because one article can have multiple categories, and I save this in a string.

Comment: And this string is a cause of the problem.

Comment: even using x.CategoryID.Contains(category.CategoryID) (if i dont want to change architecture), does not work, and give the : "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression" error.

Comment: Can you post schema of your tables and exact queries tha you use? .Contains() should work. And since it is complaining about ToString(), then you are still using it somewere.

Comment: yes i uploaded the files here : http://www.easy-share.com/1917568727/ToStackOverFlow.zip, Because I uploaded them in a free service, it may take a few mintutes to download. Thanks Vladimir. I might see your answer few hours later. because I had to leave home for university.